# How to sort the values in columns of a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have a matrix, where I need to sort the matrix column-wise.

Let's say the matrix is:

```
98 76 66 55
77 61 43 98
1  2  100 88
```

The output matrix should look like:

```
1 2  43  55
77 61 66  88
98 76 100 98
```

Can someone help me in writing a good code for the above operation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you propose to store in the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrix is a 2D list-of-lists, you could do it — without third-party modules — as shown below.

It works by first transposing the matrix (flip it over its diagonal) so the columns become rows, sorts those, and then transposes that intermediate result thereby converting the rows back into columns and undo the initial swap. Python's built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function is used to do the transposing, in conjunction with its (also built-in) [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to put the values in numerical order.

```
matrix = [[98, 76, 66, 55],
          [77, 61, 43, 98],
          [1, 2, 100, 88]]

print('before:')
print(matrix)  # -> [[98, 76, 66, 55], [77, 61, 43, 98], [1, 2, 100, 88]]
matrix = [list(row) for row in zip(*(sorted(col) for col in zip(*matrix)))]
print('after:')
print(matrix)  # -> [[1, 2, 43, 55], [77, 61, 66, 88], [98, 76, 100, 98]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it doesn't answer my question, my output should be in such a way that each column need to be sorted among the element present in that particular column.

Comment: Dharma: I think I now understand what you want and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the zip function

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your matrix is defined as a `list` of `list`s. My basic premise is that it's trivial to sort a `list`. You can just use `list.sort()`. Here, I transpose the matrix so that its *rows* need sorting, then iterate through the rows to sort.

```py
import numpy as np
def sortCols(inList):
    temp = np.array(inList).T.toList()
    for subList in temp:
        subList.sort()
    inList = np.array(temp).T.toList()
    return inList
```

Comment: Something like this could also be done without `numpy`.

Comment: Of course. In fact, something like this could also be done completely inside a `numpy` array as well. Unfortunately, I'm [not dutch.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Regardless of ones nationality, I think it's best to show folks how to do things with stock Python and its standard library unless there's a very compelling reason to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Not as pretty, but it's native.

Comment: No, that's not what I had in mind. It's not only not pretty, it has errors including one due to syntax, and even if you fix those, most importantly, it doesn't work. I suggest you revert back to your original answer (if you're sure it's runnable and works).